# How Do I Pass Dynamic JSON File name using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

How do I pass Dynamic JSON file name using Retrofit

**MainActivity.java:**

```
final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://www.domain.com/").build();
api flowerapi = restadapter.create(api.class);
```

**api.java:**

```
public interface api {

    @GET("/JSONS/flowers.json")
   void getData(Callback<List<Flower>> response);

}
```

As you can see in my above code, I am using only single/one and only flowers.json

What If I would like to call dynamic json files based on some conditions, like in some cases I have to call `flowers.json`, in some cases `roses.json` and in some cases `something.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the `@Path` annotation

```
 @GET("/JSONS/{name}")
 void getData(@Path("name") String name, Callback<List<Flower>> response);
```